# tracking tasks not completed in an executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a multithreaded application and using ExecutorCompletionService for my purpose. So far the application has been running fine and there is no issue. However there is a particular scenario - assuming there are n threads running and for some reason, some threads complete the processing later, in that case, how to make sure that the program uses the results generated by all processing threads. I am using **take()** method of this class. However I am trying to understand if there is a better approach. Ideally I am looking for a solution where by it is possible to query a data structure which stores unfinished tasks. As I am not able to create the scenario (which might take time as I need to do some kind of one time test coding), looking for a suggestion in the forum.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> how to make sure that the program uses the results generated by all processing threads.

I assume you are asking how does the consumer of the `ExecutorCompletionService` know when they have consumed the last task?  Typically you count the number of jobs submitted to the `ExecutorService` and then stop taking from the completion service after you dequeue that many jobs.

If you have a large number of jobs that you can't queue up all at once, you could have a counter as well as a `boolean done` status field.  So the `ExecutorCompletionService` will be finished when `done` is true and the job counter matches.

```
private class CompletedJobInfo {
    ExecutorCompletionService service;
    boolean done;
    int submittedCount;
}
```